# Show and allow selecting dates outside of month with @material-ui/pickers DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm currently working on a React project where the preference is to utilize the DatePicker from @material-ui/pickers.

As the title says, one of the requirements is to display also the dates outside of the current month, as well as - provided they are not disabled - allow the user to select those days, so they don't have to first click to change the month then select the date.

The one and only way thus far I could see to allow for displaying the dates outside of the current month, was by providing custom styles to my own renderDay function.

```
const styles = createStyles(theme => ({
    dayDisabled: {
        color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)",
        pointerEvents: "none"
    },
    nonCurrentMonthDay: {
        color: theme.palette.text.disabled,
    },
    highlightNonCurrentMonthDay: {
        color: '#676767',
    },
    highlight: {
        background: theme.palette.primary.main,
        color: theme.palette.common.black,
        '&:hover':{
            background: theme.palette.primary.main,
        }
    }
}));

    renderWrappedWeekDay = (date, selectedDate, dayInCurrentMonth) => {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const isSelectedDay = isSameDay(date, selectedDate);

        const dayClassName = clsx(classes.day, {
            [classes.nonCurrentMonthDay]: !dayInCurrentMonth,
            [classes.highlightNonCurrentMonthDay]: !dayInCurrentMonth,
            [classes.highlight]: isSelectedDay,
            [classes.dayDisabled]: el.props.disabled
        });

        return (
                <IconButton className={dayClassName}>
                    <span> {format(date, "d")} </span>
                </IconButton>
        );
    };
```

But I have not been able to identify any means of triggering the onChange event when clicking any date outside of the current month dates.

As I don't have too much in-depth experience when it comes to the material-ui pickers, would anyone be able to advise on whether or not it is possible to achieve the desired functionality? And if it is, how to best go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem, what we need to do is override clicking of the customized date, use React.useState to change the selected date, something like this:

```js
    const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(moment());


      renderWrappedWeekDay = (date, _ , dayInCurrentMonth) => {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const isSelectedDay = isSameDay(date, selectedDate);

        const dayClassName = clsx(classes.day, {
            [classes.nonCurrentMonthDay]: !dayInCurrentMonth,
            [classes.highlightNonCurrentMonthDay]: !dayInCurrentMonth,
            [classes.highlight]: isSelectedDay,
            [classes.dayDisabled]: el.props.disabled
        });

        return (
                <IconButton className={dayClassName} onClick={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation() // stop the propagation
                if (dayIsBetween) // use your own logic to limit selectable days
                    handleDateChange(date) // now, set state of the new selected date
                }}

                >
                    <span> {format(date, "d")} </span>
                </IconButton>
        );
    };
```

and the value of the date picker should be the state, in this case, selectedDate

```js
                                        <DatePicker

                                            variant="static"
                                            labelFunc={date => (date ? date.format("YYYY/MM/DD") : "")}
                                            value={selectedDate}
                                           
                                            renderDay={renderWrappedWeekDay}
                                            onChange={(e) => { }} // you need to override onChange otherwise you might see onChange not defined error

                                            minDate={today}
                                            maxDate={endDate}
                                        />
```

Comment: For anyone coming here, if you use @material-ui/pickers v3.3.10, don't bother, this does not work.