# KeyboardDatePicker @material-ui/pickers how to show days outside of month

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

How do I add all dates outside of the month while keeping the selection logic

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYjaw.png)

[i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqyMM.png)

If i give TextField type='date', then all dates are displayed, but all my styles are lost.

My component

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils} libInstance={momentLib}>
  <DefaultKeyboardDatePicker
    open={open}
    value={value ?? null}
    onChange={onChange}
    disableIcon={disableIcon}
    helperText={typeof userError === 'string' ? userError : errorNode || helperText}
    error={!!userError || !!errorNode}
    onClose={onClose}
    renderDays={renderDay ? renderDays : void 0}
    TextFieldComponent={TextField}
    InputProps={{
      inputRef,
      inputProps: readOnly
        ? { readOnly: true, className: classes.readonly, onClick: onOpen, 'id-qa': idqa }
        : { 'id-qa': idqa },
    }}
    InputAdornmentProps={{ onClick: onOpen }}
    PopoverProps={{ anchorEl: inputRef.current }}
    }}
    {...props}
  />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I tried passing all the props and overwriting styles, nothing worked. Can i leave all styles

```
    const WrapperTextField = () => <TextField {...props} type="date" className={clsx('MuiPickersDay-day')} />;
 ...
 TextFieldComponent={WrapperTextField}
```

Wasted a lot of time. It is strange that in such a library there is no flag to show all numbers and work with them.

I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom renderDay function to be able to show not current month dates. Here is [the example](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker#customization) of this function in docs. To be able to select those days you need to go further and override IconButton onClick inside renderDay function. For example of code take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493438/show-and-allow-selecting-dates-outside-of-month-with-material-ui-pickers-datepi) question. As I see there is no simple way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I saw all these links and thought there was a way to override the material-ui MuiPickersDay-hidden style that hides all dates. In general, I need to show dates after the end of the month, leave the option to select dates after the end of the month. I thought there was a way to make it easier.

Comment: As I see in v4.0.0-alpha.4 version there is showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth prop. It could help you. And there is date picker in next material ui with same prop (pickers moved on to main lib).